# How to use timer in Vapor (server-side Swift)?

Tags: vapor, server-side-swift

Can I use timer, such as `NSTimer` in Vapor (server-side Swift)?

I hope my server written in Vapor can do some tasks proactively once in a while. For example, polling some data from the web every 15 mins.

How to achieve this with Vapor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can accept your task timer being re-set whenever the server instance is recreated, and you only have one server instance, then you should consider the excellent [Jobs](https://github.com/BrettRToomey/Jobs) library.

If you need your task to run exactly at the same time regardless of the server process, then use `cron` or similar to schedule a [Command](https://vapor.github.io/documentation/guide/commands.html).

Comment: `Jobs` is the solution, thanks! Just one stupid question, how do I keep my server instance running without exiting (if I remove `droplet.run()`)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; why do you want to remove `droplet.run()`?

Comment: @tobygirffin since I used node.js before, so I keep considering the server instance can do the same (not just a web framework).

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand. What is achieved by removing the serving part of your Vapor app?

Comment: sorry, I am new to Vapor & server-side Swift. How about this... is there a library for server-side Swift for this node.js async library: https://github.com/caolan/async ?

Answer (score 7):

If you just need a simple timer to be fired, once or repeatedly you can create it using the `Dispatch` `schedule()` function. You can suspend, resume and cancel it if needed.

Here is a code snippet to do it:

```
import Vapor
import Dispatch

/// Controls basic CRUD operations on `Session`s.
final class SessionController {
let timer: DispatchSourceTimer

/// Initialize the controller
init() {
    self.timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource()
    self.startTimer()
    print("Timer created")
}


// *** Functions for timer 

/// Configure & activate timer
func startTimer() {
    timer.setEventHandler() {
        self.doTimerJob()
    }

    timer.schedule(deadline: .now() + .seconds(5), repeating: .seconds(10), leeway: .seconds(10))
    if #available(OSX 10.14.3,  *) {
        timer.activate()
    }
}


// *** Functions for cancel old sessions 

///Cancel sessions that has timed out
func doTimerJob() {
    print("Cancel sessions")
}

}
```

Comment: Hey, will the scheduled tasks take place even if the app isn't running?

Comment: Hmmm. Not seeing anything here specific to cancelling a timer.