# How to execute a function every n hours in server side swift?

Tags: swift, vapor

I'm looking for a Swift counterpart to Django's [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) which allows a function to execute every given amount of time.

I need a solution that works on server side Swift, meaning not all of Foundation is available, and something that's not for iOS / Mac.

I am using the Vapor framework.

Comment: I have answered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41898944/how-to-use-timer-in-vapor-server-side-swift/55539678#55539678) with a code snippet

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have three main options.

For a timer managed within your server app (i.e. restarting the server resets your timers) you can use `Dispatch`:

```
import Dispatch
let timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource()
timer.setEventHandler() {
  // task
}
timer.scheduleRepeating(deadline: .now() + .seconds(3600), interval: .seconds(3600), leeway: .seconds(60))
timer.activate()
```

Similarly, you can use the third party [Jobs](https://github.com/BrettRToomey/Jobs) package created by a Vapor contributor:

```
import Jobs
Jobs.add(interval: .hours(1)) {
  // task
}
```

If you want the function to be run at particular times of day independent of your server's uptime, there's no beating `cron` (or its relatives). Your cron job should either call a Vapor [Command](https://docs.vapor.codes/2.0/vapor/commands/) on the binary, or hit a protected URL-route with `curl`.

Comment: do you know how to do this in vapor 3?

Comment: @NevinJethmalani The top two options do not depend on a particular Vapor version and should work.

Comment: Jobs looks interesting. It's concerning to me though that it hasn't received an update in 2 years.

Comment: The Jobs package, although outdated a bit, still works very nicely on Vapor 4