# Vapor 3 Swift 4 How to Make a Timer

Tags: swift, server-side, jobs, vapor

The new Vapor has come with new upgrades, meaning many imports don't work with the new software.For example, [Jobs](https://github.com/BrettRToomey/Jobs), a minimalistic job system in Swift worked perfectly for older version of Vapor but not newer, is there any alternative to create Timers as regular timers don't work for server side Swift?

Comment: I have answered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41898944/how-to-use-timer-in-vapor-server-side-swift/55539678#55539678) with a code snippet

Answer (score 0):

The 'best' way to do it would be to call directly down to NIO - see their documentation [here](https://apple.github.io/swift-nio/docs/current/NIO/Protocols/EventLoop.html#/s:3NIO9EventLoopP12scheduleTaskAA9ScheduledVyqd__GAA10TimeAmountV2in_qd__yKctlF)

Note that there's nothing wrong with using Jobs in Vapor 3. It just doesn't fit as well with the updated Thread model, but it should still all work.